# How to access hosts file?

Tags: file-system, hosts

I am following [these instructions](https://www.modmy.com/how-modify-hosts-file-your-android-device) to modify the `hosts` file (map IPs to names) and it says it is under `/system/etc`. When I went into my Android file browser, I did not find that directory. Is it because the phone is not rooted and how can I access that file?

Comment: If your device is not rooted, you cannot edit that file, no. Even if it is in a different location. To edit the hosts file you need root access.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If it's for debugging an android app you might want to use an emulator ;)

Comment: I am trying to see my laptop on the same wifi network by its name and not by its IP address and I am unable to do DNS on the wifi router -- so I would like to assign the name to its IP in the Android hosts file

Comment: If anyone else reach this page searching for where the hosts file for your os, you can use [this site](http://www.whereismyhostsfile.com/) to locate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an app like Hosts Go that doesn't require root and allows you to set custom host entries.

The app is available from Google Play.